Spring library compatibility confusion
According to the release train available here, it appears that I should be able to use Spring Boot 3.3.1 with Spring Cloud 2023.0.2. In addition to these, I am also trying to use Spring Cloud AWS v3.2.0-M1. With these versions in place, I am recieving the following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeCompatibilityVerifier' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/configuration/CompatibilityVerifierAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.configuration.CompositeCompatibilityVerifier]: Factory method 'compositeCompatibilityVerifier' threw exception with message: Spring Cloud/ Spring Boot version compatibility checks have failed: [[VerificationResult@56ec31ca description = 'Spring Boot [3.3.1] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train', action = 'Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [3.2.x] .
You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn].
If you want to learn more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check the [Release Trains] section.
If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]']]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)

Why do these combinations not work together? Is the documentation or the code wrong, or have I missed something altogether?

Does it happen without spring cloud AWS? That is managed independently from spring boot and spring cloud and may bring in older dependencies?

I do receive the error when I compile the library that pulls in Spring Cloud AWS. Can someone from the Spring Cloud AWS team comment on this?

Perhaps you can ask in this Spring Cloud AWS issue or discussion regarding Spring Boot 3.3.x compatibility.
